# How do I create an RGB CIImage from 3 8-bit gray images?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, core-image

I have 3 `CIImage` objects that are gray 8-bpp images that are meant to be the 8-bit R, G, and B channels of a new image.  Aside from low-level image pixel data operations, is there a way to construct the `CIImage` (from filters or some other easier way)

I realize I can do this by looping through the pixels of a new RGB image and setting it from the gray channels I have -- I was wondering if there was a more idiomatic way to work with channels.

For example, in Pillow for Python, it's `Image.merge([rChannel, gChannel, bChannel])` -- I know how to code the pixel access way if there is no built in way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book, [Core Image for Swift](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/core-image-for-swift/id1073029980?mt=13), covers how to do this and provides the code to do it here:

https://github.com/FlexMonkey/Filterpedia/blob/master/Filterpedia/customFilters/RGBChannelCompositing.swift

The basic idea is that you need to provide a color kernel function in GPU shader language and wrap it in a CIFilter subclass.

NOTE: The code is not copied here because it's under GPL, which is an incompatible license with StackOverflow answers.  You can follow the link if you want to see how it's done, and use it if it's compatible with your license.